# Commutative operation benefits

Tags: algebra, compilers, term-rewriting-systems

With an associative operation I can rewrite a computation tree

```
        +
       / \
      +   4
     / \
    +   3
   / \
  +   2
 / \
0   1
```

to be more efficient in parallel.

```
     +
   /   \
  +     +
 / \   / \
1   2 3   4
```

Are there situations where assuming *commutativity* offers computation benefits?

Comment: Isn't commutativity exploited (required?) by MapReduce?  (E.g. https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse490h/08au/lectures/mapred.pdf) Maybe somebody who knows more can elaborate.

Comment: I'd expect commutative operations on sparse structures to be often optimizable by commutativity, but I can't find a good example

Answer (score 6):

One example where commutativity helps is in computing the determinant. [Nisan](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103418.103462) showed that any non-commutative algebraic formula that computes the $n \times n$ determinant must have size $2^{\Omega(n)}$. On the other hand, the determinant is computable by commutative algebraic formulas of size $n^{O(\log n)}$.